# Parametrization of volume integral

Tags: real-analysis, integration, multivariable-calculus, volume, multiple-integral

For computate the lines integral (first and second species) we need to find a parametrization of the curve when we are integrating
For the surface integral we do the same, but this time we search a parametrization for the surface.
And for the volume integral? How can i parametrize the volume?